# Bibliography Style cite style

Tags: bibliographies

How can I change cite style? If I cite a book I get, for example, [KA40]. I would like to have something like [Ka40]. I'm using BibTeX, `\usepackage[numbers,square]{natbib}` and `\bibliographystyle{alphadin}`. Does it depend on the bibliography style?

Comment: With the `alphadin` style uppercase will be used for initials and lowercase for the other letters of the names. Are you experiencing something different? If so, please add to your question a [minimal working example](http://www.minimalbeispiel.de/mini-en.html) illustrating the problem.

Comment: @Herbert you are right! I didnt realize that used allways the book with two authors. Sorry for dummy question.

Answer (score 2):

I suppose that "KA40" is a ref to an entry with two authors, the reason why it is in uppercase